# Выделение строки в JTable

Tags: java

Подскажите, плиз, можно ли после подсоединения модели к таблице и отображения данных, программно выделить одну сроку? Есть же метод getSelectedRow, а setSelectedRow нету :( ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел - changeSelection.